# ajaxurl usage for a custom function

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am creating a custom form in one of my wordpress post and its getting submitted using AJAX post method. Here is my code:

HTML for button :

```
<button onclick="result()" type="button" name="result_submit" id="result_submit" >Submit</button>
```

Jquery:

```
function result(){

        $.ajax({
            url  :ajaxurl,
            type :'POST',
            action :'expense',
            success: function(data){
                $("#result").html(data);
            }
        });             
}
```

To use ajaxurl I added below php code in head section :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
</script>
```

And then added below codes to my functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_expense', 'expense_check' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_expense', 'expense_check' );


    function expense_check(){
    include_once 'dbConnection.php';

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

    $income = "select SUM(amount) as incomeNumber FROM wp_formdata WHERE entry_type='Income'";
    $response = '';

    if (! mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$income)) {
         $response = '<h1 style="color:red;padding-top:5%;">SQL Error !!</h1>';
    } else {
         mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
         $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
         $income_sum = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
         $response = "Total Income is ".$income_sum['incomeNumber'];
    }

    echo $response;
    }
```

But its not working. I am getting below error in console:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: What’s the URL of the page you are trying to make this call from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code in your active theme's function.php

```
add_filter( 'allowed_http_origins', 'add_allowed_origins' );
function add_allowed_origins( $origins ) 
{
    $origins[] = 'https://yoursite.com';
    return $origins;
}
```

Now ajax call from `https://yoursite.com` to your site's ajax url will have the appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response.Use below code

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://site1.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        ...
    },
    success: function(doc) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks. Its working on chrome now, but firefox still shows the same error. cleared the cache and cookies and no luck.. Any idea why its not working in FF ?

Comment: if it works well please upvote and marked as useful so it will help others

Comment: still then i'm checking for firefox

Comment: add this line in your ajax call : `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://yoursite.com`